# How to reverse this command in Mac OSX?

Tags: python, django, testing, command, tinymce

I tried to follow tutorial on django-tinymce docs to verify if everything is installed and configured properly, however, I have the following error even if I start a new Virtualenv.

```
ImportError: No module named testtinymce.settings
```

I think this might have been cause because of the following command that I've run before.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='testtinymce.settings'
```

How can I reverse this?

Comment: did you mention the app name correctly? Where settings.py file is located?

Comment: Yes. I am just trying to uninstall TinyMCE. I have removed it and any reference to the app from the project. It doesn't work. Let me restart the PC and see what happens.

Comment: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=''` this would reset the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env variable.

Comment: Apparently this was set with the current terminal session. Restarting the PC fixed it. I guess I could've just restarted my terminal too.